# POSIX: glob() only finds first match

Tags: c, posix, glob, libc

I have difficulties figuring out how to properly use the `glob()` function.

This is my simple test code:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *path;
    if (argc > 1) {
        path = argv[1];
    } else {
        path = "/foo/bar/";
    }
    glob_t pglob;
    int glob_res = glob(path, 0, NULL, &pglob);

    switch (glob_res) {
    case GLOB_ABORTED:
        printf("Glob failed: read error\n");
        break;
    case GLOB_NOMATCH:
        printf("Glob failed: no match\n");
        break;
    case GLOB_NOSPACE:
        printf("Glob failed: oom\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Matches: %lu\n", pglob.gl_pathc);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < pglob.gl_pathc; ++i) {
            printf("%s\n", pglob.gl_pathv[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I have a directory like this:

```
$ ls
a  b  glob  glob.c
```

I would expect a call to `./glob *` to print all 4 files, however it just tells me about the first one:

```
$ ./glob *
Matches: 1
a
```

What silly beginner's mistake am I making?

Comment: The shell is doing the expansion before your program sees it, and you're only processing the first command line argument, which in this case would be `'a'`, so that's all you see.

Comment: The shell expands `*` which you don't want. Run as `./glob '*'` to avoid shell expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments: the shell already did the globbing:

`./glob *` was resolved to `./glob a b glob glob.c` and therefore the call to the `glob()` function used just `a` as pattern.

Calling `./glob '*'` solved the problem.